# Resize the JQGrid column at runtime

Tags: jqgrid

I need to resize the JQGrid column at runtime.

For eg:  the column width for the column was 100px when it is loaded. I need to change it to 200 afterwards.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this using the jqGrid API. From the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options):

> As mentioned above the options in colModel can be get or set using the methods getColProp and setColProp. Below are options which can not be changed dynamically when the grid is constructed (If changed they do not have effect or will cause the grid errors). For some of these options there are methods available to change the value:
>
> - name
> - width
> - resizable
> - label (method avail.)