# jqGrid - how to reset grid column widths?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

If users manually resize jqGrid columns, how can you reset the column width back to whatever the original values were?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there are any built in methods for reseting the widths, leaving the option of recording them at creation and restoring them at a later point. Unfortunately, this functionality is the same as it was [10 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502947/resize-the-jqgrid-column-at-runtime/2503473#2503473) with column width being one of the few options that cannot be changed once the grid has been created. I even tried the newest version of the grid just to be sure (3.8.2) and it does not allow you to change the column sizes.

```
$('#jqGrid').getColProp(colName).width;  //Properly retrieves value of column width    
$('#jqGrid').setColProp(colName, {width: newWidth}); //Does nothing visually
$('#jqGrid').getColProp(colName).width;  //Returns newWidth, although it doesn't show it on page
```

I don't know if it would be worth it, but you could try Oleg's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) of destroying the current grid and creating a new one in its place. The practicality of this solution I suppose would be dependent upon how you are getting the data and how long it would take to re-bind the data to a new grid.